# android webview on no connection error

Tags: java, android, webview, network-connection

I am trying to show a custom error of no connection, but its not working below is the code
and in the manifest.xml i have provided network status. Connection() is checking the network status in the class. Hope this helps in sorting out the problem.

```
package com.testing.webview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static final int DIALOG_NONETWORK = 0;
    WebView mWebView;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        if(!Connection()){
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Sorry you need an Internet connection!  Please try again when the network is available.";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
            finish();
        }

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
        mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }


    public boolean Connection() { 
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo(); 
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()){ 
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        } 
    }


    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {        

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you finishing the activity after there is no connection?

Have the Toast like:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Network is down",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And then make the view show some sort of Button to "Retry" the network request, that's what i would do anyway. The Toast isn't currently showing probably because the activity is closed straight away after the toast, so there isn't enough time to show it